# map frame from robot_localization

Tags: imu, navigation, gps, navsat-transform, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create the standard tf frames specified in REP 105 (map, odom, and base_link) using the robot_localization package.  I only have GPS and IMU sensors available.  So far I have been able to create the odom and base_link frames, but I am having trouble creating the map frame.

This is my launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ukf_localization_node"
     name="ukf_localization" clear_params="true" ns="ackermann_vehicle">

    <param name="frequency" value="30"/>
    <param name="sensor_timeout" value="0.1"/>
    <param name="two_d_mode" value="false"/>
    <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
    <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
    <param name="base_link_frame" value="base_link"/>
    <param name="world_frame" value="map"/>

    <param name="imu0" value="imu/data_compass"/>
    <rosparam param="imu0_config">[false, false, false,
                                   true,  true,  true,
                                   true,  true,  true,
                                   true,  true,  true,
                                   true,  true,  true]</rosparam>
    <param name="imu0_differential" value="true"/>
    <param name="imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration" value="true"/>

    <param name="gps0" value="odometry/gps"/>
    <rosparam param="gps0_config">[true,  true,  true,
                                   false, false, false,
                                   false, false, false,
                                   false, false, false,
                                   false, false, false]</rosparam>
    <param name="gps0_differential" value="false"/>
  </node>

  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node"
      name="navsat_transform_node" ns="ackermann_vehicle" respawn="true" output="screen">
    <param name="magnetic_declination_radians" value="0"/>
    <remap from="imu/data" to="imu/data_compass" />
    <remap from="gps/fix" to="navsat/fix" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

If I set the world_frame parameter to "odom", then things seem to work but I only have odom and base_link frames.  If I set the world_frame to be "map", like above, then I get this error message: Could not obtain transform from odom->base_link.

Note that I am new to ROS, so my trouble may be conceptual.  I would appreciate any help someone is willing to offer.  Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203989/map-frame-from-robot_localization/) by [Sam Bishop](https://answers.ros.org/users/21272/sam-bishop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2015-03-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-03-01**:
You also appear to have X, Y, and Z velocity set to true for your IMU. Does it report velocities?

**Comment by [Sam Bishop](https://answers.ros.org/users/21272/sam-bishop/) on 2015-03-01**:
No.  I had intended to review all of my use/don't-use settings after getting the frames sorted out, but those three are obviously wrong.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Starting with [REP-105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html) was the right move. Your answer lies in the section marked "Frame Authorities." The *odom* and *map* frames are both world-fixed frames. If you are running two instances of `ekf_localizaton_node` or `ukf_localization_node`, then instance 1 provides the *odom*->*base_link* transform, and you want instance 2 to generate a *map*->*base_link* transform. However, `tf` structures the transforms as a tree, and so *base_link* cannot have two parents. Therefore, instance 2 uses its internal *map*->*base_link* transform, combined with the *odom*->*base_link* transform being generated by instance 1, and creates a *map*->*odom* transform. This allows the user to still transform from *map*->*base_link* (*map*->*odom*->*base_link*).

However, the use case above is really only necessary if you have some source of odometry, such as from wheel encoders. In that case, you'd fuse the IMU and odometry in instance 1, and the IMU, wheel odometry, and GPS in instance 2. Since you only have an IMU and GPS, just run a single instance, and set the *world_frame* to *odom*. Note that your position will jump around as you get new GPS measurements, however.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sam Bishop](https://answers.ros.org/users/21272/sam-bishop/) on 2015-03-01**:
Thank you!  Your answer has helped a few things finally click for me.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Tom Moore's answer is correct (thanks again!), but I want to report what my final launch file looks like.

**There is an error with my launch file above, and I would hate for someone to be misled by it.**  I was under the impression that the sensor variable prefixes ("odom", "imu", "pose", and "twist") used in the documentation were simply convention, and that the localization nodes keyed off of the types of the messages coming from each sensor.  But that isn't true--the prefixes are the key--and variables that don't have the right prefix are ignored.  So if you are feeding data from `navsat_transform_node`, then use an "odom" prefix!

I also removed some redundant configuration from my launch file.

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="ukf_localization_node"
    name="ukf_localization" clear_params="true" ns="ackermann_vehicle">

    <param name="frequency" value="30"/>
    <param name="sensor_timeout" value="2"/>

    <param name="imu0" value="imu/data"/>
    <rosparam param="imu0_config">[false, false, false,
                                   true,  true,  true,
                                   false, false, false,
                                   false, false, false,
                                   true,  true,  true]</rosparam>
    <param name="imu0_differential" value="true"/>
    <param name="imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration" value="true"/>

    <param name="odom0" value="odometry/gps"/>
    <rosparam param="odom0_config">[true,  true,  true,
                                   false, false, false,
                                   false, false, false,
                                   false, false, false,
                                   false, false, false]</rosparam>
  </node>

  <node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node"
      name="navsat_transform_node" ns="ackermann_vehicle" respawn="true" output="screen">
    <param name="magnetic_declination_radians" value="0"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Sam Bishop](https://answers.ros.org/users/21272/sam-bishop/) with karma: 131 on 2015-03-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Anirvan0102](https://answers.ros.org/users/27058/anirvan0102/) on 2016-06-09**:
Hello Sam,
I want to know tha does'nt the Navsat_transform_node also need odometry data as mentioned in the http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization/Tutorials/GPS%20Integration ? Does the Navsat_transform_node run without odom data ? Please specify I really need the information